# Yii 2: virtual fields in ActiveRecords

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I use MySQL and Yii 2. In database exist `table 'Regions' with column 'coordinates'`. Type of this column is point.

In SQL I can write:
`"SELECT X(coordinates) as x, Y(coordinates) as y"` and `"INSERT INTO Regions SET coordinates = PointFromText('POINT(".$x." ".$y.")')"`.

But I don't know how make ActiveRecord model. I want this (unchanged the database):

```
$item = Regions::findOne(1);
echo $item->x." ".$item->y;
$item->x = $new_x;
$item->y = $new_y;
$item->save(); // data saved in 'coordinates' column
```

Methods `'set...()'` and `'get...()'` not help me. I want to avoid additional queries to the database.

Please help me to do it.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-your-startup-with-php-geolocation-and-google-places--cms-22729 . On the page earch for 'point'.

Comment: robsch, thank you. But here used additional queries. \yii\db\Expression to save and 'Select AsText(gps)' for read.

Comment: Maybe, I must customize query class and no other way. Not simple ... :(

Comment: Post your solution as answer. Will be helpful to others.

Comment: I make a temporary solution with additional requests. If I make customization query class, I will publish it here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with Yii2 just like that:

```
public $longitude, $latitude;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    $this->location = new \yii\db\Expression("GeomFromText(:point)", [
        ':point'=>'POINT('. $this->longitude.' '.$this->latitude.')'
    ]);
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}


/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->select([
        '*', 'X(location) as longitude', 'Y(location) as latitude'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Function find is interesting. But \yii\db\Expression needs one additional query to the database. I want only one query for find and only one for save.

Comment: Why do you think so? I am sure Expression DOES NOT make additional query. It just adds additional param to your model saving query.